# React - How to control export/import limitations

Tags: reactjs

This might get a bit tricky to wrap your head around but here goes nothing:

I have class(es) that renders a component, and they use a function inside the class(es). Why not a method you might ask, because I need this method to be accessable by other classes. However each function is Class specific, which is why I can't make a generic helper function that is global.

Here is an example

```
export function generateProblem(){
   // generates a problem lol
}

ClassA {
   generateProblem();
   //does other stuff
   render()
}

export default ClassA
```

`Class B is basically the same as Class A except generateProblem is unique to Class B`

```
import generateProblem as gPA from "./ClassA"
import generateProblem as gPB from "./ClassB"
Class C {
   // Randomly call either gPA() or gPB();
   render()
}
```

The current problem I am facing is that the function call in Class C doesn't work. I am getting the following error:
`Class constructor ClassA cannot be invoked without 'new'`
and it points to the line where I call the function

is there something wrong with the way I am importing/exporting the function? or does React not allow 2 different export statements of a function/class.

Additional details -
the exported function is using `function()` notation and not `function = () => {` notation because i heard the latter does not have a prototype or something making it unconstructable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you're importing the function. When you write `import something from "./foo"`, you get the default export from `./foo`. If you write `import {something} from "./foo"`, you get the named export named `something.

In your case, your imports need to look like this:

```
import { generateProblem } as gPA from "./ClassA"
import { generateProblem } as gPB from "./ClassB"
```